# How to remove Azure MSSQL audit logs

Tags: sql-server, azure, audit

Looks like we had SQL audit with default retention period 0. I've noticed increased pricing for the azure storage account. Azure documentation says, that if I change the retention period, existing logs won't be affected/deleted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auditing#subheading-2

> Important
>
> The default value for retention period is 0 (unlimited retention). You can change this value by moving the Retention (Days) slider in Storage settings when configuring the storage account for auditing.
>
> If you change retention period from 0 (unlimited retention) to any other value, please note that retention will only apply to logs written after retention value was changed (**logs written during the period when retention was set to unlimited are preserved, even after retention is enabled**)

How to clear logs older than 180 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can delete the logs which older than 180 days manually.

Usually, the audit log is stored in Storage.
[image]

Audit will create a container to store the logs in your Storage account:
[image]

**SQL server folder:**

[image]

**Database folder:**

[image]

**Choose a database**:

[image]

According to my understanding (If I miss something, please correct me.) :

- If you set the retention period to other Day (not 0), the new log is
  stored in folder `SqlDbAuditing_Audit`.
- If the retention period is 0, the database audit logs are stored in
  `SqlDbAuditing_Audit_NoRetention`, the Server audit logs are stored in
  `SqlDbAuditing_ServerAudit_NoRetention`.

You can clear logs older than 180 days in folder `SqlDbAuditing_Audit_NoRetention` or `SqlDbAuditing_ServerAudit_NoRetention`.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yesterday i've changed default retention from 0 to 180 days. Now i see folders `*_Audit` and `*_Audit_NoRetention` . These audit logs uses 51 TiB, while actual database size is about 50Gb